# karma jasmine test number of anchors in html

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

consider the following code segment:

```
<nav>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">&times;</a>
    <a routerLink='/home'>Home</a>
    <a routerLink='/contact'>Contact</a>
</nav>
```

How may I test to that there is exactly 3 anchor for example:

```
it('should have 3 number anchor, () => {
    const element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(element.find('a').length).toEqual(3);
  });
```

Please advise.

Comment: the way you are testing is absolutely fine. is it not working?

Comment: element.find does not work in angular 2 or higher. The function is provided in angularjs (angular 1).  element.find is not a function is the error I get from my test in angular versions higher then 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expect(element.querySelectorAll('a').length).toEqual(3);
```

and if you can ad a class to all the anchors, say "link". then we can be more specific as below
    `expect(element.querySelectorAll('.link').length).toEqual(3);`